# Centering column in Three Part Table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, threeparttable

I'm having trouble when trying to center columns in a three part table enviroment. My code:

```
 \begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\let\TPTrlap\relax

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
            >{}R
            >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}R
            >{\hsize=1.0\hsize}R
            >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}R
                            @{\hspace{0.5\tabcolsep}}}
\caption{Custo Fixo Total}
\label{tab:} \\
\midrule
\upshape Material& Custo (R\$) &Quantidade&Total (R\$) \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Custo Fixo Total (cont.)}
\label{tab:} \\
\midrule
\upshape Material& Custo &Quantidade&Total \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape continua na próxima página}
\endfoot
\midrule[1pt]
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot


 Acabamentos MDF &-&-& \\
\addlinespace
 Botão Push Button&1,12/ unidade&1&1,12 \\
\addlinespace
 Chapa MDF&59,80/m^{2}&1,4&83,72\\
\addlinespace
 Dobradiças&0,33/ unidade&3&0,99 \\
\addlinespace
 Espátula plástica&0,80/ unidade&1&0,80\\
\addlinespace
 Estilete&0,90/ unidade&1&0,90\\
\addlinespace
 Fio paralelo \SI{2,5}{\mm^{2}}&3,24/m&1,5&4,86\\
\addlinespace
 Interruptor&1,05/ unidade&3&3,15\\
\addlinespace
 Micro retífica + eixo flexível&129,90/ unidade&1&129,90\\
\addlinespace
 Rolo pequeno de pintura&3,39/ unidade&1&3,39 \\
\addlinespace
 Secador&34,76&1&34,76 \\
\addlinespace
 Tira de \textit{LED}&24,90/ 50 cm&5&124,50 \\
\addlinespace
Tomadas fêmea &1,00/ unidade&3&3,00 \\
\addlinespace
 Tomada macho&1,00/ unidade&1&1,00 \\
\addlinespace
 Ventosa&1,00/ unidade&1&1,00 \\


\end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{table}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: I would like at least the colum "Quantidade" centered]

Comment: Please tell us how the `R` column type is defined.

Comment: Oh sorry I don't know that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `R` to `c`:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
                >{}R
                >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}c
                >{\hsize=1.0\hsize}c
                >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}c
```

Comment: This won't work. The `{\hsize=x\hsize}` prefixes must be associated with a variable-width column type, such as `X` (or one of it's derived forms). If we had `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`, then `>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C` would work.